# How to cause static block to run?

Tags: java, timer

I've seen many answers on this topic but still can't find a clean solution.

```
public class ProcessScheduler {
    static {
        Timer timer=new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                LogProcessorServiceImpl.processPageRequestsLogs();
            }
        }, 0, 120);
    }
}
```

How do I make this execute and be happy with quality solution? My application is based on Spring (unfortunately) and I know I can reference this class in one of my controllers and it'd probably work. But that's silly. There just must be a better way. I'm on Tomcat with no EJB support, so timer annotation will not work for me. Also, I don't want to do CRON. I want to schedule all my maintenance tasks within this scheduler class.

Servlet classes can be loaded via web.xml (1). Can we do something similar on non-servlet classes?

Comment: static block executes on class load. It will be executed on load, if you don't want may be you need to do something like a method and call, is that what you want.

Comment: Method call would still require this class referenced somewhere else. This is just as dirty. This scheduler should be fully autonomous.

Comment: @jacekn, why is it unfortunate that your app runs on spring? Spring provides robust scheduling

Comment: At least you should load this class somewhere in your program to make the static block run. Is there an approach that can load this class automatically in your environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of writing this in a static block, I would prefer to

- write an [event listener](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B15904_01/web.1012/b14017/filters.htm#i1000654) that extends [`javax.servlet.ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)
- move that piece of code into the [`contextInitialized`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) method
- define the [`contextDestroyed`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html#contextInitialized%28javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent%29) method to cancel the timer
- configure the class as `<listener>` in `web.xml` file for my application.

  ```
  <listener>
      <listener-class>
          com.vikdor.webapps.ProcessSchedulerListener
      </listener-class>
  </listener>
  ```

Comment: Well, I was going to use a simple servlet for this but I'm trying your listener. The servlet implements the ServletContextListener and is loaded. But the contextInitialized() method does not run. I guess I need to read up on this, unless you can explain faster.

Comment: Did you add the class as a listener in your web.xml? I just updated my answer with potential entry.

Comment: Yes, I did add listener definition to web.xml and the server was restarted, as well. When I switched to a simple servlet it worked fine so I'll leave it at that. To me, it's pretty much the same solution, so I'm accepting your answer. Thanks.